# Laravel 7 - Problem with unique constraint on update

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

I'm trying to add unique validation to my model, but there is an error when I tried to update the data.

The table:

```
acq_m_budgets
==================================
budget_id serial NOT NULL,
budget_code character varying(15) NOT NULL,
budget_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
ma_code character varying(10),
start_period timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
end_period timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
budget numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
credit numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
debet numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
balance numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
reserve numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
created_by character varying(100) NOT NULL,
created_on timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
updated_by character varying(100) NOT NULL,
updated_on timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT PK_AcqMBudgets PRIMARY KEY (budget_id),
CONSTRAINT UN_AcqMBudgets UNIQUE (budget_code)
```

My model: **AcqMBudgets.php**

```
class AcqMBudgets extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'budget_id';
    public $sortable = ['budget_code', 'budget_name', 'ma_code', 'balance', 'updated_on'];
    protected $fillable = ['budget_code', 'budget_name', 'ma_code', 'start_period', 'end_period', 'budget', 'credit', 'debet', 'balance', 'reserve', 'created_by', 'created_on', 'updated_by', 'updated_on'];
    
    protected $attributes = [
        'budget' => 0,
        'credit' => 0,
        'debet' => 0,
        'balance' => 0,
        'reserve' => 0,
    ];
    
    public static function createRules()
    {
        return [
            'budget_code' => 'required|unique:acq_m_budgets,budget_code|max:15',
            'budget_name' => 'required|max:100',
            'ma_code' => 'max:10',
            'start_period' => 'required',
            'end_period' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    
    public static function updateRules($id)
    {
        return [
            'budget_code' => 'required|unique:acq_m_budgets,budget_code,' . $id . '|max:15',
            'budget_name' => 'required|max:100',
            'ma_code' => 'max:10',
            'start_period' => 'required',
            'end_period' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

My Controller: **BudgetController.php**

```
...

public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate(AcqMBudgets::createRules());
        
        $model = new AcqMBudgets;
        $post = $request->only($model->getFillable());

        $post['start_period'] = (!empty($post['start_period'])) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $post['start_period']))) : null;
        $post['end_period'] = (!empty($post['end_period'])) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $post['end_period']))) : null;
        
        $model->fill($post); 
        $model->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('acq.view.master.budget', ['id' => $model->budget_id, 'rf' => 'a']);
    }

...

public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate(AcqMBudgets::updateRules($request->input('budget_id')));
        
        $model = AcqMBudgets::find($id);
        $post = $request->only($model->getFillable());
        
        $post['start_period'] = (!empty($post['start_period'])) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $post['start_period']))) : null;
        $post['end_period'] = (!empty($post['end_period'])) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $post['end_period']))) : null;
        
        $model->fill($post);
        $model->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('acq.view.master.budget', ['id' => $model->budget_id, 'rf' => 'e']);
    }

...
```

On the model, I already separated the rules for create and update method. The difference is in the updateRules(), there is a primary key parameter which is needed in the array of rules.

On the controller, on `update` function, there is an error which stated: `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: ...from "acq_m_budgets" where "budget_code" = $1 and "id" <> $2 ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "acq_m_budgets" where "budget_code" = N01 and "id" <> )`.

The primary key I used is integer and incremental, but due to some circumstances, the name of the primary key cannot be just `id`, so I changed it into `budget_id` and already declared it at the beginning of the model. Going by the error message, it seems Laravel keeps trying to compare with this `id` field instead the one I declared. What needs to be done to fix this?

**UPDATE IN CODE:**
I used `Rule` namespace on createRules and updateRules on model:

```
    public static function createRules()
    {
        return [
            'budget_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('acq_m_budgets', 'budget_code'), 'max:15'],
            'budget_name' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            'ma_code' => ['max:10'],
            'start_period' => ['required'],
            'end_period' => ['required'],
        ];
    }
    
    public static function updateRules($id)
    {
        return [
            'budget_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('acq_m_budgets', 'budget_code')->ignore($id, 'budget_code'), 'max:15'],
            'budget_name' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            'ma_code' => ['max:10'],
            'start_period' => ['required'],
            'end_period' => ['required'],
        ];
    }
```

When I tried to update the data, I made changes to some fields except the `budget_code`. The changes won't be saved if I didn't change the `budget_code` field as well, since it always give an error: `"budget_code" has already been taken`. I use `dd($post)`, and the fields I changed is passed on perfectly.

Comment: I don't think, you get this error for validations. Because it's an SQL error. You did the validation before use Elequent. Somehow primaryKey is not working, if you change `AcqMBudgets::find($id);` to `AcqMBudgets::where('budget_id', $id);` may be it will work.

Comment: he gets it on the ignore clause i'm pretty certain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Rule namespace, where you can call unique through that. For this to work you have to use arrays, for validation rules instead of strings, this is the better approach for readability anyways.

`Rule::unique` has the method `ignore()` where the second parameter is the id column, this can be seen [here](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/43d43cf19263eab7e8772ecc7c6f03365ce563a3/Rules/Unique.php#L53).

```
'budget_code' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('acq_m_budgets', 'budget_code')->ignore($id, 'budget_id'),
    'max:15'
]
```

Comment: Bonus point: i would never store your validation rules like this, instead i would use form request for storing this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Using arrays actually indeed increase readability, but since the official documentation for Laravel 7.x only mentioned about using strings, I never tried it until now :) Back to the topic, I tried your suggestion to use `Rule` namespace. While the error is resolved, when I updated columns such as `budget_name`, etc (other than the `budget_code` itself), it shows an exception that the `budget_code` has already been taken

Comment: try to dd($post) before you fill the data to see if it is as expected or dd() your model before calling save.

Comment: is the budget code already in the database? right now it is a little sparse with debug information on your problem and hard to know when we can't see it all

Comment: I updated the table structure above. So for example, I added a new budget data record with `budget_code`: "T2020", `budget_name`: "My budget on 2021". When I updated my `budget_name` to "My budget on 2020", and keep the `budget_code` as it is, it won't get updated, since it says the `budget_code` has already been taken. It will get updated, if I change the `budget_code` as well to a new non existent one.

Comment: You are sure, your post data does not set the budget_code to null or similar?

Comment: Yep, the `budget_code`'s value is not null or empty string

Comment: The code you have here works fine so i must be either data or something completely different

Comment: I can't believe the mistake I made. Actually, your answer is the correct answer, except the `Rule::unique('acq_m_budgets', 'budget_code')->ignore($id, 'budget_code')` part, it should be `Rule::unique('acq_m_budgets', 'budget_code')->ignore($id, 'budget_id')`, since the primary key id `budget_id`